# What exactly is Time and Space?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics, time, cosmology

**Question description so that anyone can evaluate and answer accordingly**

I don't know what is the formal process for a theory to get accepted by the science community, please guide me on how to proceed further?

1. I have self-studied this subject for the last many years (never got the opportunity to study at University level) so please bear with less technicality in my language.
2. I have developed a theory about Time and Space and answered this question myself (tried to summarize the whole concept) to explain the Theory. I believe that the first step is to bring it here in front of experts for them to evaluate the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not meant for providing feedback on users' own theories. It is for answering questions based on already published literature.

Comment: Thanks Conifold...  actually I have a question mentioned in the description that I don't know what is the formal process for a theory to get accepted by the science community, please guide me on how to proceed further.
I have given details so that anyone can evaluate my theory and answer accordingly.

Comment: That is also not a topic for this site, you can try [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/). Typically, an experienced academic mentor is helpful.

Comment: That link is nice... although I am going to ask my question there also. Still, I feel that subject matter expert in this field are here so their advice would be more specific to my question.

Comment: The question has no relation with the text. The question seems to be "How to get a theory accepted". Sadly, this is not the forum for that.

Comment: RodolfoAP ... I understand, could you please advise me where I should ask about the evaluation of this theory if I don't have any academic mentor. This is the only platform where I can find some insight if this theory is worthwhile or not.

Comment: One of the most important things to know about space & time, is Noether's theorem https://youtu.be/TDjgQ_megMI Sean Carroll has just done a series on his channel with episodes unpacking continuous symmetries and symmetry groups, which can get you deeper into Noether's insight.

Answer (score 3):

here is a very condensed summary of the process of getting the scientific community to seriously entertain your new theory.

1. you must familiarize yourself with everything already accomplished in that field of study. If you cannot demonstrate your knowledge & mastery of that field, no one in it will have any reason to take you seriously. And whatever your new model of the world might be, it must successfully account for everything that is already known in that field.
2. you must have an effortless fluency in advanced mathematics, because that is the universal language of the physics community, and the language in which all our existing models of the world are written. If you cannot express your model of the world in this language, you are not doing physics- you are doing philosophy.
3. you must identify the unanswered questions in that field i.e., the areas where the accepted models in it have shortcomings and fail to yield answers that agree with experiment. Your new model must successfully answer those questions without contradicting anything else in the field already known and understood within the context of existing models.
4. your new model must make explicit and precise predictions about the behavior of the world which can then be experimentally tested to see whether or not they are correct. If your theory makes no predictions, or if it cannot be tested, then its validity cannot be demonstrated and studying it is a waste of time.
5. finally, you must share your theory with all the experts in the field to ensure that your expression of it is error-free in all regards. This is called *peer review*.